# How to convert a constant into a ProgramError type in Rust/Anchor when returning in a function?

Tags: rust, solana

Learning Rust and Anchor here.
I'm trying to return a ProgramError for a specific scenario in this program, but when using the into() method inside #[program] an error msg is shown.

I've checked the documentation:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html

Here's the error message:

> the trait bound `anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError: From<ErrorCode>`
> is not satisfied the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
> <anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError as From>
> <anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError as
> From<anchor_lang::error::Error>>   <anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError
> as Fromstd::io::Error>   <anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError as
> From> required for `ErrorCode` to implement
> `Into<anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError>`

Here the program code.

```
#[program]
pub mod solana_twitter {
    use super::*;
    pub fn send_tweet(
        // SendTweet was used as generic type to link the context to this function
        ctx: Context<SendTweet>,
        topic: String,
        content: String,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let tweet: &mut Account<Tweet> = &mut ctx.accounts.tweet;
        // Signer is used to guarantee that the account is owned by the author
        let author: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.author;
        let clock: Clock = Clock::get().unwrap();

        if topic.chars().count() > 50 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::TopicTooLong.into());
        }
        if content.chars().count() > 280 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::ContentTooLong.into());
        }

        tweet.author = *author.key;
        tweet.timestamp = clock.unix_timestamp;
        tweet.topic = topic;
        tweet.content = content;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The ErrorCode enum.

```
#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("The provided topic should be 50 characters long maximum.")]
    TopicTooLong,
    #[msg("The provided content should be 280 characters long maximum.")]
    ContentTooLong,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are suppose to use the `anchor_lang::err` [macro](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.27.0/anchor_lang/macro.err.html) to wrap the error.

it should be

```rs
if topic.chars().count() > 50 {
    return err!(ErrorCode::TopicTooLong);
}
if content.chars().count() > 280 {
    return err!(ErrorCode::ContentTooLong);
}
```

See: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/errors

Also I think you should be returning `Result<()>` instead of `ProgramResult`.

Comment: It was recommended for the documentation to use ProgramResult when building with Solana Anchor, which is the same as result<(), ProgramError>. In my limited knowledge, that is what I understood. It's a more effective way to handle errors.

Comment: Just be clear, I know it works if I use result<()> (mainly because its the same as Result<(), ErrorCode>, which is what I have there.

Comment: I'm testing a solution, I have to implement a From trait to convert ErrorCode to ProgramError. It's in the From/Into documentation, but I got confused. I just need to make it work now. Thanks for the suggestion!